# Optimization of a clockwise sort algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, sorting

So this is an optimization question, which I could not find answered.

I have written some code for computing the convex hull of a given set of random points. For comparative purposes, I have made my own, slow O(n³) algorithm, using some old OpenGL stuff to visualize it. Because of the nature of the slow convex hull algorithm, the points are not sorted at all. So the sort takes place just after the computation of the CH.

My problem is that up till 1000 points, I have a visual result in less than a second. But for 10000 points, it takes over 15-20 minutes (I have not waited beyond that). *However* if I skip the sorting code and let opengl display the convex hull vertices unsorted, it takes less than a minute. So it's the ClockWise sorting that's eats up all that time. Check the code (some names don't make sense as they are defined elsewhere) :

```or-tag
// This code actually compares every pair iteratively with respect to the center point
// Consider a given vector "convex", which contains all the convex hull points unsorted

.
..
...
....

int avgx,avgy,sumx=0,sumy=0;

for (int i=0;i<convex.size();i++){
    sumx+=convex.at(i).at(0);
    sumy+=convex.at(i).at(1);
}

avgx=sumx/(convex.size()/2.0); //something like an internal point
avgy=sumy/(convex.size()/2.0);

sort(convex.begin(),convex.end()); //x-sort 
int det,tempx,tempy;
for (int i=0;i<convex.size()-1;i++){
    x1=convex.at(i).at(0);
    y1=convex.at(i).at(1);
    x2=convex.at(i+1).at(0);
    y2=convex.at(i+1).at(1);
    det=(x1-avgx)*(y2-avgy)-(x2-avgx)*(y1-avgy); 
    if (det<0){ //on which side of O-X1 lies X2?
        tempx=convex.at(i).at(0); //swapping points 
        tempy=convex.at(i).at(1);
        convex.at(i).at(0)=convex.at(i+1).at(0);
        convex.at(i).at(1)=convex.at(i+1).at(1);
        convex.at(i+1).at(0)=tempx;
        convex.at(i+1).at(1)=tempy;
        i=-1; //check again the new vector from the beginning
    }
    }
return convex;
```

The display part:

```or-tag
glColor3f(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
glPointSize(3);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
        glVertex2f(convexHull.at(i).at(0),convexHull.at(i).at(1));
    }
glEnd();
```

From what I've seen, this approach (by comparing cross products) is the most efficient. However, before this I wrote some filthy code which actually was faster, as it gave me a visual result within 8 minutes. I don't want to keep that because it's too dirty and long, this one is cleaner but very slow (if it actually works at all....). So, am I bound to wait so much for a CW sort of 10000 convex points, or there is something I am missing?

I'd appreciate any thoughts, let me know if I need to include anything else.

Comment: Are you saying that you already have a convex hull, and just want to sort the points into a polygon (clockwise) for visualization? Did you get these points from a convex hull algorithm? I ask because all the CH algorithms I know of give the points in polygon order, i.e. they output the points in the order they occur in a polygon.

Comment: Yes, the points are the output of my brute force algorithm. It is intentionally like that, because I want to compare the results with the GeoLib library, which uses the Graham's algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, this problem is a little strange. Most 2D convex-hull algorithms (all that I know of) give out the list of points (vertices) in clockwise or counterclockwise order, or they can be modified trivially to do so.

In any case, since there are several good 2D convex-hull determination methods that run in **O(N^2)** or faster, you can use one of those to "sort" your data into clockwise order. What I'm saying is that you can run a CH algorithm on your data and get the result in the order you want.

Here's a sample code I had lying around that I think would do what you want:

```
#define TURN_DIR(p1,p2,p3)  (p1.x * p2.y - p1.y * p2.x + \
                             p2.x * p3.y - p2.y * p3.x + \
                             p3.x * p1.y - p3.y * p1.x)
#define LAST(cntnr)         (cntnr).back()
#define BEFORE_LAST(cntnr)  (cntnr)[(cntnr).size() - 2]

void ConvexHull (std::vector<Point> & pts)
{
    std::sort (pts.begin(), pts.end());

    std::vector<Point> lower, upper;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        while (lower.size() > 1 && TURN_DIR(BEFORE_LAST(lower), LAST(lower), pts[i]) <= 0)
            lower.pop_back ();
        while (upper.size() > 1 && TURN_DIR(BEFORE_LAST(upper), LAST(upper), pts[i]) >= 0)
            upper.pop_back ();

        lower.push_back (pts[i]);
        upper.push_back (pts[i]);
    }

    upper.insert (upper.end(), lower.rbegin() + 1, lower.rend() - 1);
    pts.swap (upper);
}
```

There are a few points to consider:

1. The above code receives its input and returns its output in the same argument: `pts`.
2. The `Point` structure is a simple struct (or class) with two public members `x` and `y`, and a less-than operator (an `operator <`) that compares them very simply based on `x` first and then `y`.
3. I believe the running time of the above code is **O(N*log(N))**, but it certainly is no worse than **O(N^2)**.
4. The returned points will be in *clockwise* order. If you want counterclockwise, you only need to change that last two lines.
5. This code will not handle the case that all points have the same X coordinates (I think!)
6. Other than that, this is a functional and fast and simple 2D convex-hull implementation.
7. If there are consecutive points in the input that lie on the same line, this implementation removes them. If you don't want that, you can replace the `<= 0` and `>= 0` tests in the `while` loops with `< 0` and `> 0` respectively.

Let me emphasize this: although the above code is a CH implementation, you can use it just to sort your points in a clockwise winding order (if they already form a convex hull.)

Comment: This code looks like the way the O(nlogn) Monotone Chain algorithm works (by handling right/left turns). So actually you're suggesting "sorting" the convex points by applying this algorithm on them as if they were the starting random points? That's actually a good idea, thanks.

Comment: @thetrooper Well, I didn't know the name, so thank you for that! And yes, that's what I'm suggesting. Since the time complexity is not higher than a simple sort, and I don't know of any sorting algorithm that can take advantage of the fact that these points lie on a convex hull to do the sort faster, I think it is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @thetrooper By the way, did you try the code I've given here? Adapting in to your data structures should be easy. Just replace `Point` with `vector<int>` (or `typedef` it) and fix the `TURN_DIR` macro by replacing `.x` and `.y` with `[0]` and `[1]` respectively.

Comment: No I didn't try the code itself, because I wanted to avoid a pure CH algorithm. I will try it and I'll get back to you :).

Comment: It worked flawlessly and took minimal time (few secs for 10k points). Truth is, this was part of an assignment I had. I took the chance to research a bit on this kind of algorithms. The given O(n^3) algorithm in pseudocode ended like "sort anti/clockwise" but didn't say how. So I don't know if using a fast CW could be considered a cheat(although the CH is already computed). However I will accept it as best answer and add the options I had (this-algorithm, the lists-one I mentioned, the atan2 one and the cross product comparing one) in my report. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You have implemented [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which is O(n<sup>2</sup>). You can get O(n log(n)) by using the STL `sort` with an appropriate comparison functor.

Here's a first effort; it uses a non-transitive comparitor, but it seems to work in my test cases and I *think* it's generally correct:

```
struct clockwise : public binary_function<vector<int>, vector<int>, bool>
{
  bool operator()(vector<int> A, vector<int> B)
  {
    int det=(A[0]-avgx)*(B[1]-avgy)-(B[0]-avgx)*(A[1]-avgy);
    return(det<0);
  }

  static int avgx, avgy;
};

int clockwise::avgx = 0;
int clockwise::avgy = 0;

...

int clockwise::avgx=sumx/(convex.size()/2.0);
int clockwise::avgy=sumy/(convex.size()/2.0);
sort(convex.begin(),convex.end(), clockwise()); //clockwise-sort
```

**EDIT:**

The non-transitive comparitor wasn't a good idea. This is more reliable:

```
#include <math.h>

...

struct clockwise : public binary_function<vector<int>, vector<int>, bool>
{
  bool operator()(vector<int> A, vector<int> B)
  {
    return(atan2(A[0]-avgx, A[1]-avgy) < atan2(B[0]-avgx, B[1]-avgy));
  }
}
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for. It took only 3 minutes to display the CH for 10000 points, GeoLib took 1min. The compare class makes it very fast and elegant. Thanks. I unfortunately can't vote up both of you yet :).

Comment: Well, it turned out to be a bit lucky. Sometimes it produces a good CH, but sometimes it also messes up. I can't see a pattern though. Sure thing is that it's not about collinear points but something else, because the edges tangle even on 4-point CHs with all points having different xs and ys. Does sort with comparison produce as safe results as bubble?

Comment: I will check that too, but isn't using atan2 considered a bad practice? It computes the atan2 while we don't need the atan itself, but rather the relative position (not even angle) of the 2 points. I am just starting with comp. geometry and graphics and while researching I read some comments here saying that.

Comment: @thetrooper: Yes, it is a little expensive, though it gives us O(n log(n)). Well, third time's the charm...

Comment: It is fast, but it unfortunately keeps tangling lines (only sometimes though). Could it be because of atan2 messing the + - of the angle? Although it is made not to do so. Anyway, the job is done, but I will maybe check it again some time. Thanks.

Comment: @thetrooper: Could you give me an example where it tangles the lines?

Comment: I am sorry, consider it an ultra-failure by me. It works perfectly now. I was maybe running the build from your previous suggestion, as I have laying around 6-7 different cpps with different code. Sorry again.